# A conjecture on writing a function as a sum of uncountably many points

Tags: real-analysis

Define the sum of the non-negative numbers $\{r_s \mid s \in S\}$ $S$ uncountable to be

$$\sup _{D \subseteq S} \sum _{d \in D} r_d$$

($D$ being finite), which exists if this supremum is finite.

Define a point function to be a function from $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb R$ that is $0$ everywhere except for a single point, where it takes a positive value.

Suppose we have an uncountable family of point functions $f_r: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ indexed by $r \in [0, 1]$. Define the pointwise sum function $S[a, b]: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ as

$$S[a, b] (x) = \sum _{r \in [a, b]} f_r (x) \ .$$

It can be shown that if $S[0, 1]$ is well defined, then so is $S[0, a]$ for any $a$ such that $0 \le a < 1$.

Assume that if $S[0, 1]$ is well defined. Does it follow that for Lebesgue almost every $a \in [0, 1]$ the function $S[0, a]$ is discontinuous at at least one point?

Comment: Even in https://math.stackexchange.com, which is probably where this belongs, they do ask you to show your thoughts and your attempts in a "do my homework for me" type of problem.

Comment: It’s not a homework problem. Why do you feel it belongs on stack exchange?

Comment: It belongs in **math.stackexchange** not merely in "stack exchange".  Once it is there, and you show your work up to now, we will be able to give you hints to help you solve it completely.

Comment: It’s hard to give a coherent account of what I’ve tried since I’ve used a lot of non-rigorous reasoning which didn’t end up yielding any rigorous results. Also, why do you feel it belongs on math.stackexchange.com? It’s not a homework problem, and I’ve asked a few professional mathematicians who haven’t been able to solve it.

Comment: New posters get less benefit of the doubt about whether a question is research-level.  Showing a bit of rigorous reasoning which yields partial results would help.

Comment: Idk, I’ve seen textbook exercises being posted here and the response seemed fine. Most recently I saw one from Hairer’s Rough Paths book which got a very good answer. I checked the faq before posting, and it stated as long as it’s a question you’re genuinely thinking about and trying to answer, it’s okay to post it here. I’ll try to update with what I’ve been able to get so far, but tbh they’ve all been dead ends.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar "A decreasing sequence of continuous functions converging to a continuous limit converges uniformly,", right? That is, indeed, homework but I'm not sure I would give it even as a qualifier problem in such a disguise.

Comment: @fedja Does that statement help solve this problem?

Comment: @NgZe-An There is nothing in the problem beyond that and the standard trickery for showing that a subset of $\mathbb R$ is countable. But I should admit that it takes at least 15 minutes to build a mental picture of the setup. Try to think a bit more, but if you decide to give up, let me know and I will post my solution.

Comment: Please do post it, I can’t seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, here goes as promised.

Fix $\delta>0$ and consider the set $A_\delta$ of all points $a$ such that $S[0,a]$ is continuous and $\max f_a>\delta$ (this maximum is just that exceptional positive point value in your case but we can do arbitrary non-negative not identically $0$ functions). If we could find $a_n,a\in A_\delta$ such that $a_1>a_2>\dots\to a$, then $S[0,a_n]$ would be a decreasing sequence of continuous functions converging  to the continuous limit $S[0,a]$ pointwise but not uniformly (because $\max(S[0,a_n]-S[0,a])\ge\max f_{a_n}>\delta$). Thus, for every $a\in A_\delta$, there exists an open interval $(a,b_a)$ free from points in $A_\delta$. Since we can place at most countably many disjoint open intervals on $\mathbb R$, $A_\delta$ is countable for each $\delta>0$. Hence the set of $a$ for which $S[0,a]$ is continuous (which is, say $\cup_{k\ge 1}A_{1/k}$) is also countable and, thereby, of Lebesgue measure $0$.

Just made it community wiki not to collect reputation from homeworks :-)

Comment: Edit: never mind I’m an idiot LOL

Comment: No, you aren't :lol:

Comment: Cute. Do you have any positive results, showing that several $S[0,a]$ could be continuous? Obviously, $f_r(x)=\delta_r(x)$ gives that $S[0,a]$ is continuous if and only if $a=1$. But I don't see how to get anything else.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Just consider some mapping $\psi$ that maps several intervals bijectively to $[0,1]$ one after another and use $f_r(x)=\delta_{\psi(r)}(x)$. If you want a homework with a star on it, try to figure out if *every* countable set can appear as the set of parameters of continuity. I'll give no hints on that one, but, perhaps, somebody else will ;-)